Raspberry Pi Pico not recognized after updating micropython
I bought a batch of picos in Nov 2021. Been working with 2 of them since with no problem. Decided to update the micropython firmware. The units then lost connection to the computer with no COM port available. They will now mount in boot mode and Thonny will download the file to the pico but then fails with a message that a com port cannot be found. Tested with both Windows 11 Thonny, Raspberry Pi Thonny and manual drag/drop. Neither computer can find a pico com port. Tried 2 other unused picos in the same batch and had the same problem from the start. Found a post about installing correct USB drivers Pi Pico W is not recognised by thonny after installing micro python but that did not fix the problem; however, it supplied another error message of "Device Descriptor Request Failed". Thought about trying to install an earlier version of microphython but went down a time consuming wormhole to stuff beyond my skill level. Is there a source of compiled earlier versions I can test?
Broke out a couple of pico W I bought in Dec 2022 and all installed and worked with no problem.

Found the compiled archive at https://micropython.org/download/RPI_PICO/
Loaded ver 1.17 by drag and drop. USB connection restored on all units. Version 1.23.0 also works for both Raspberry Pi and Windows 11.
If you have an older pico, you may want to stick with older firmware.
